# Corda NodeDriver MissingContractAttachments for Cash even with packages to scan set

Tags: corda

Getting the MissingContractAttachments exception:

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: net.corda.core.transactions.MissingContractAttachments: Cannot find contract attachments for [net.corda.finance.contracts.asset.Cash]

Have my NodeDriver's packages set to:

```
...
withExtraCordappPackagesToScan(
    Arrays.asList.of("com.cordatemplate.cordapp, net.corda.finance, 
        net.corda.finance.contracts.asset")
)
...
```

But the error remains. Also tried it with:

```
...
.withExtraCordappPackagesToScan(
                    Arrays.asList("com.cordatemplate.cordapp, 
    net.corda.finance, net.corda.finance.contracts.asset, 
    net.corda.finance.schemas, net.corda.finance.contracts.asset.Cash, 
    net.corda.finance.contracts.asset.Cash.Commands.Issue")
)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each package needs to be passed as an individual string, rather than a stringified list.

So instead of:

```
withExtraCordappPackagesToScan(
    Arrays.asList.of("com.cordatemplate.cordapp, net.corda.finance, 
        net.corda.finance.contracts.asset")
)
```

You would write:

```
withExtraCordappPackagesToScan(
    Arrays.asList.of(
        "com.cordatemplate.cordapp", 
        "net.corda.finance", 
        "net.corda.finance.contracts.asset")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [corda documentation](https://docs.corda.r3.com/api-contract-constraints.html#debugging), the two main sources of `MissingContractAttachments` errors is from either not setting up the Cordapp packages in tests or from having the wrong fully qualified contract name.

Since it seems that you have already attempted to include the packages, you likely have the incorrect fully qualified contract name.

From the docs:

> For example, you’ve defined MyContract in the package com.mycompany.myapp.contracts, but the fully-qualified contract name you pass to the TransactionBuilder is com.mycompany.myapp.MyContract (instead of com.mycompany.myapp.contracts.MyContract).